# Zooming versus change in window width

Tags: html, css, zooming

With all my reading on zooming with css, I have reached the conclusion that it's **not** really a good idea considering the limited support of zooming with all Browsers. In this regard, I cannot help but notice that Microsoft's WORD does not zoom the contents of the Word documents. Maybe they're right.

But let me trudge on ...

As a learning experience, what I'd really like to see with zooming is
= exactly what happens when re-sizing the Browser window.  That is, element containers + font sizes + etc, shrink when contracting the window size (zoom out) and expand when increasing the window size (zoom in).

But, still maintaining the layout UNTIL a certain limit; e.g., when the width of the round corner box reaches a certain width say 80% of the device's width

For example:

[image: **enter image description here**]

BTW, the above is all block centered.

For example, the width rounded corner box increases with a bigger window = zoom in, and the box's width decreases with a smaller window
= zoom out.

I wish ditto for zooming, but zooming withOUT changing the window width, i.e., just for the contents of the window.

*WHAT DOES HAPPEN:*

**with zooming in**, everything appears to be doing well

**with zooming out**, okay UNTIL a couple of CMD-plus's. At this point, the rounded corner border shifts right and beyond the view of the Browser window and the super ugly horizontal scroll bar appears.

HTML:

```
<section class="roundedBodyCornersWrapper zoomStyleRule centerBlock elemPadding">

    <div class="roundedBodyCorners">

<img class="headerImage centerImage" src="images/Broken_Heart.gif" alt="crying" />

<section class="roundedTextCornersWrapper centerBlock elemPadding">
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: white;   /* around oval */
    margin:           2.0em;
    font-size:        120%;
    min-width:        300px;
}

.zoomStyleRule {
    width:  75%;      /* always put fall-back spec 1st */
    width:  auto\9;   /* IE8 = exception to fall-back spec */
    width:  75vw;     /* even if this isn't here, still does not work */

    height: auto;
}

.roundedBodyCornersWrapper {
    /* center via  .centerBlock in layout */
    /* padding via .elemPadding in layout */
}

.roundedTextCornersWrapper {
    padding-bottom: 2.0em;   /* + a tad extra above .mainContent */
}


.headerImage {
    /*
        original size = 888px X 448px (55.5em X 28em)
    */
    width:          75%;
    width:          auto\9;   /* IE8 exception */

    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.centerBlock, .centerImage {
    display:      block;
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.infoHeader {
    font-family:    Georgia, Helvetica;
    font-size:      130%;    /* 130% x the % in body */
    color:          #fff;
}
```

BTW, everything does not work as already described even when I have

```
<meta name="viewport" ...>
```

and

```
@viewport {
}
```

appropriately placed.

In the interests of total disclosure, I am no longer certain of what dimensions change when the window resizes or when zooming out/in occur.  I see the GUI changes ...

Comment: I can't say I follow... media queries are used to place content in relation to the size of the browser window.  What are you attempting to do?  I'm not 100% up to date on ARIA, but the only time I've seen someone successfully zoomed in a *lot* was a near totally blind person, even then I think it was handled by the operating system, not CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, for Heaven's Sake ...

```
body {
    background-color: white;   /* around oval */
    margin:           1.0em;
    font-size:        120%;
 /*
    min-width:        300px;   // Oh ... for Heaven's Sake!!!
 */
}
```

**WHY does the elimination of min-width eliminate my zooming problems??**